# Ternary operator error... a valid React element must be returned?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx, ternary

I've got this simple exercise on react components to work with an **if conditional** but I wanted to try using a **ternary operator** instead. The problem is that now I get an error telling me:
*"TonightsPlan.render(): a valid React element must be returned..."*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const fiftyFifty = Math.random() < 0.5;

// New component class starts here:
class TonightsPlan extends React.Component
  {
    render()
      {
        fiftyFifty ?
        <h1>Tonight I'm going out WOO</h1>:
        <h1>Tonight I'm going to bed WOOO</h1>;
      }
  };

ReactDOM.render(<TonightsPlan/>, document.body);
```

So I guess there's something wrong with the way I'm using the ternary operator here but I can't tell what it is... I could really use some help to figure that out, please!

Comment: You don't `return` something from `render` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine, just the return in render is missing. J

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const fiftyFifty = Math.random() < 0.5;

// New component class starts here:
class TonightsPlan extends React.Component
  {
    render()
      {
        return (
          (fiftyFifty) 
            ? <h1>Tonight I'm going out WOO</h1>
            : <h1>Tonight I'm going to bed WOOO</h1>;
         )
      }
  };

ReactDOM.render(<TonightsPlan/>, document.body);
```

Comment: I thought I couldn't use "return" with ternary operator since it returns by default, but returning the whole operation instead makes a lot of sense now... thanks a lot!